# Serialization of Data Structure with Object References to JSON Using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I want to serialize a data structure to JSON with Jackson 2.13.3. **The serialization works, only it does not work in the way I intend.**
I created a simplified example data structure to show what the desired serialization is.

The data structure consists of a main `Container`, which contains a list of `Element`s. The elements have some links between them.

In the example I create the following linking structure of the elements:

```
startTop <--> endTop
    ^          ^
    |          |
    |          |
    v          v
    startBottom     <-->     endBottom
```

#### I want to get the following output

The goal is that the serialization represents the linkage data via the IDs of the linked information. The full serialization of the elements should only occur in the top level list of the container. This does not correspond the order in which jackson encounters the elements during serialization.

```json
{
    "allElements": [{
            "id": "startBottom",
            "successor": "endBottom",
            "predecessor": null,
            "upperNeighbours": ["startTop", "endTop"],
            "lowerNeighbours": null
        },
        {
            "id": "endBottom",
            "successor": null,
            "predecessor": "startBottom",
            "upperNeighbours": null,
            "lowerNeighbours": null

        },
        {
            "id": "startTop",
            "successor": "endTop",
            "predecessor": null,
            "upperNeighbours": null,
            "lowerNeighbours": ["startBottom"]
        },
        {
            "id": "endTop",
            "successor": null,
            "predecessor": "startTop",
            "upperNeighbours": null,
            "lowerNeighbours": ["startBottom"]
        }
    ]
}
```

#### I do get the following output

jackson puts the full serialization of an object wherever it encounters the object first, as can be seen in the output I currently get.

```json
{
  "allElements" : [ {
    "id" : "startBottom",
    "successor" : {
      "id" : "endBottom",
      "successor" : null,
      "predecessor" : "startBottom",
      "upperNeighbours" : null,
      "lowerNeighbours" : null
    },
    "predecessor" : null,
    "upperNeighbours" : [ {
      "id" : "startTop",
      "successor" : {
        "id" : "endTop",
        "successor" : null,
        "predecessor" : "startTop",
        "upperNeighbours" : null,
        "lowerNeighbours" : [ "startBottom" ]
      },
      "predecessor" : null,
      "upperNeighbours" : null,
      "lowerNeighbours" : [ "startBottom" ]
    }, "endTop" ],
    "lowerNeighbours" : null
  }, "endBottom", "startTop", "endTop" ]
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The java code:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Element startBottom = new Element("startBottom");
    Element endBottom = new Element("endBottom");
    Element startTop = new Element("startTop");
    Element endTop = new Element("endTop");

    startBottom.setSuccessor(endBottom);
    startTop.setSuccessor(endTop);
    endBottom.setPredecessor(startBottom);
    endTop.setPredecessor(startTop);

    startBottom.setUpperNeighbours(List.of(startTop, endTop));
    startTop.setLowerNeighbours(List.of(startBottom));
    endTop.setLowerNeighbours(List.of(startBottom));

    Container container = new Container();
    container.setAllElements(List.of(startBottom, endBottom, startTop, endTop));

    ObjectMapper mapper =
        new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    ObjectWriter prettyPrintWriter = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    System.out.println(prettyPrintWriter.writeValueAsString(container));
  }
}

class Container {
  public List<Element> getAllElements() {return allElements;}
  public void setAllElements(List<Element> allElements) {this.allElements = allElements;}
  private List<Element> allElements;
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")
class Element {
  Element(String id) {this.id = id;}

  private String id;

  // May be null
  private Element successor;

  // May be null
  private Element predecessor;

  // May be empty, which for us is the same as being null
  private List<Element> upperNeighbours;

  // May be empty, which for us is the same as being null
  private List<Element> lowerNeighbours;

  public String getId() {return id;}

  public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}

  public Element getSuccessor() {return successor;}

  public void setSuccessor(Element successor) {this.successor = successor;}

  public Element getPredecessor() {return predecessor;}

  public void setPredecessor(Element predecessor) {this.predecessor = predecessor;}

  public List<Element> getUpperNeighbours() {return upperNeighbours;}

  public void setUpperNeighbours(List<Element> upperNeighbours) {this.upperNeighbours = upperNeighbours;}

  public List<Element> getLowerNeighbours() {return lowerNeighbours;}

  public void setLowerNeighbours(List<Element> lowerNeighbours) {this.lowerNeighbours = lowerNeighbours;}
}
```

**Edit:** Added that the serialization does work, but not in the intended way.

Comment: Serialization shouldn't be that hard, you'd just need to look for how to use `successor.id` for the value of `"successor"` etc. I'm pretty sure there's an annotation or attribute for this but I can't check atm. (`@JsonIdentityInfo` might be the one) - Deserialization might be harder if needed.

Comment: You were right, thanks! I would upvote, but I cannot because I am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Thomas commented, I have to add before the fields in question:

```java
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
      property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
```

The element class then becomes:

```java
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")
class Element {
  Element(String id) {this.id = id;}

  private String id;

  // May be null
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
      property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private Element successor;

  // May be null
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
      property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private Element predecessor;

  // May be empty, which for us is the same as being null
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
      property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private List<Element> upperNeighbours;

  // May be empty, which for us is the same as being null
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
      property = "id")
  @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
  private List<Element> lowerNeighbours;

  public String getId() {return id;}

  public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}

  public Element getSuccessor() {return successor;}

  public void setSuccessor(Element successor) {this.successor = successor;}

  public Element getPredecessor() {return predecessor;}

  public void setPredecessor(Element predecessor) {this.predecessor = predecessor;}

  public List<Element> getUpperNeighbours() {return upperNeighbours;}

  public void setUpperNeighbours(List<Element> upperNeighbours) {this.upperNeighbours = upperNeighbours;}

  public List<Element> getLowerNeighbours() {return lowerNeighbours;}

  public void setLowerNeighbours(List<Element> lowerNeighbours) {this.lowerNeighbours = lowerNeighbours;}
}
```

This (with the other code from the question) generates the desired output:

```json
{
  "allElements" : [ {
    "id" : "startBottom",
    "successor" : "endBottom",
    "predecessor" : null,
    "upperNeighbours" : [ "startTop", "endTop" ],
    "lowerNeighbours" : null
  }, {
    "id" : "endBottom",
    "successor" : null,
    "predecessor" : "startBottom",
    "upperNeighbours" : null,
    "lowerNeighbours" : null
  }, {
    "id" : "startTop",
    "successor" : "endTop",
    "predecessor" : null,
    "upperNeighbours" : null,
    "lowerNeighbours" : [ "startBottom" ]
  }, {
    "id" : "endTop",
    "successor" : null,
    "predecessor" : "startTop",
    "upperNeighbours" : null,
    "lowerNeighbours" : [ "startBottom" ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mark your members `successor` and `predecessor` in your class `Element` with annotation `@JsonIgnore` to prevent endless loop. And your code should work. But I can even suggest something that will make it even simpler. I wrote my own utility that allows you to serialize any class to Json and deserialize from Json back into an instance of a class. It uses Jackson library under the hood. The code that would do the job for you would be as simple as this:

```
try {
  System.out.println(JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(container));
}catch(IOException ioe) {
  //Handle exception
}
```

Where `container` is the instance of your container class. Here is the Javadoc for class [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). This class is part of MgntUtils library written and maintained by me. The library can be obtained as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)